# How to test NGINX redirect

Tags: http, redirect, nginx

I just configured a Nginx with the conf file below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name teste.mysite1.com                              
    server_name  ^/$ https://www.mysite2.com.br permanent;
}
```

Then I would try to see if it is responding with `301 redirect.`

I tried:

```
curl -i -H "Host: teste.mysite1.com" http://http://ec2-18-236-182-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I thought it would redirect but it's still returning `http 200` response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your server block is wrong, you used `server_name` before the redirection logic. You need to configure it like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name teste.mysite1.com                              
    rewrite  ^/$ https://www.mysite2.com.br permanent;
}
```

Be aware that this configuration will **only** redirect the website root. Remove `/$` if you want any url on teste.mysite1.com redirected.

Comment: Just fixed.. but I am still getting 200.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name teste.mysite1.com
    return      301  https://www.mysite2.com.br;
}
```

Reload Nginx to use the new configuration.

```
curl -i -H "Host: teste.mysite1.com" http://ec2-18-236-182-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```